# Add background image in HTML

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, background-image

Hi,

I am trying to add background images to the following:

- under the body (so the image will cover the whole page, even when I scroll)
- under section class="jumbotron text-center" or maybe just under main role="main"

But nothing I do seems to work.
I added code snippets but there's bootstrap so I linked a jsfiddle code.

```css
:root {
  --jumbotron-padding-y: 3rem;
}

.jumbotron {
  background-image: url("gigi.jpg");
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #f8f9fa!important;
}

.navbar a {
  color: black!important;
}

.nav-link {
  font-size: 12px;
}

/* Search button */

.input-group {
  width: 180px; /* will it lose responsiveness?*/
  /*border-bottom: 1px solid;*/
}

.input-group .form-control {
  padding: .275rem .50rem;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  /*padding-right: 32px;*/
}

.input-group .form-control:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

.input-group input { 
  text-indent: 5px;
}

/*
#navbarNav {
  position: relative; //might need this to keep magnifying glass in right position
}
*/

#navbarNav .fa-search { 
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: -33px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

/* .transparent-input {
  background: transparent; /* maybe make this slight whiter than background
} */


.jumbotron {
  padding-top: var(--jumbotron-padding-y);
  padding-bottom: var(--jumbotron-padding-y);
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .jumbotron {
    padding-top: calc(var(--jumbotron-padding-y) * 2);
    padding-bottom: calc(var(--jumbotron-padding-y) * 2);
  }
}

.jumbotron p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.jumbotron-heading {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.jumbotron .container {
  max-width: 40rem;
}

footer {
  padding-top: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
}

footer p {
  margin-bottom: .25rem;
}

.box-shadow { box-shadow: 0 .25rem .75rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .05); }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">#RF LOGO PIC</a>
      </div>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="
      navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign-in</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Wishlist</a>
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Shopping bag</a>

        </ul>
        <div class="form-search">
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="/action_page.php">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control transparent-input" placeholder="Expand e.g. Zara">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
       <span class="fas fa-search"></span>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <main role="main">

      <section class="jumbotron text-center">
        <div class="container">
          <h1 class="jumbotron-heading">Marketing catchphrase</h1>
          <p class="lead text-muted">Shop from our collection of Women's, Men's wear at affordable prices, greatest quality etc...</p>
          <p class="float-left-custom">
            <a href="#">New</a>
          </p>
          <p class="float-left-custom">
            <a href="#">Women</a>
          </p>
          <p class="float-left-custom">
            <a href="#">Men</a>
          </p>
          <p class="float-left-custom">
            <a href="#">Kids</a>
          </p>
          <p class="float-left-custom">
            <a href="#">Sale</a>
          </p>
          <p class="float-left-custom">
            <a href="#">Our weekly picks</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </section>

      <div class="album py-5 bg-light">
        <div class="container">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="images/thumbnail.svg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="images/thumbnail.svg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="images/thumbnail.svg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="images/thumbnail.svg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="images/thumbnail.svg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="images/thumbnail.svg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="images/thumbnail.svg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="images/thumbnail.svg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="images/thumbnail.svg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </main>
```

Comment: How to set background image(https://www.wikihow.com/Set-a-Background-Image-in-HTML)

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work

Comment: Are you sure the URL to your image is the right one and the image is readable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won’t see any image on `body` or `[role=main]` because they contain elements with `background-color` (`.jumbotron` and `.album`) covering them.

That being said, having an image should work, as with the snippet below.

What I did was really just adding the URL to a Wikipedia image and change its `background-size` property.

If you want to have your background image on `[role=main]`, you can remove `.bg-light` from `.album`.

```css
:root {
  --jumbotron-padding-y: 3rem;
}

.jumbotron {
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f3/Palacio_Hasht_Behesht%2C_Isfah%C3%A1n%2C_Ir%C3%A1n%2C_2016-09-20%2C_DD_75-77_HDR.jpg/800px-Palacio_Hasht_Behesht%2C_Isfah%C3%A1n%2C_Ir%C3%A1n%2C_2016-09-20%2C_DD_75-77_HDR.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #f8f9fa!important;
}

.navbar a {
  color: black!important;
}

.nav-link {
  font-size: 12px;
}

/* Search button */

.input-group {
  width: 180px; /* will it lose responsiveness?*/
  /*border-bottom: 1px solid;*/
}

.input-group .form-control {
  padding: .275rem .50rem;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  /*padding-right: 32px;*/
}

.input-group .form-control:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

.input-group input { 
  text-indent: 5px;
}

/*
#navbarNav {
  position: relative; //might need this to keep magnifying glass in right position
}
*/

#navbarNav .fa-search { 
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: -33px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

/* .transparent-input {
  background: transparent; /* maybe make this slight whiter than background
} */


.jumbotron {
  padding-top: var(--jumbotron-padding-y);
  padding-bottom: var(--jumbotron-padding-y);
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .jumbotron {
    padding-top: calc(var(--jumbotron-padding-y) * 2);
    padding-bottom: calc(var(--jumbotron-padding-y) * 2);
  }
}

.jumbotron p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.jumbotron-heading {
  font-weight: 300;
}

.jumbotron .container {
  max-width: 40rem;
}

footer {
  padding-top: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
}

footer p {
  margin-bottom: .25rem;
}

.box-shadow { box-shadow: 0 .25rem .75rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .05); }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">#RF LOGO PIC</a>
      </div>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="
      navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign-in</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Wishlist</a>
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Shopping bag</a>

        </ul>
        <div class="form-search">
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="/action_page.php">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control transparent-input" placeholder="Expand e.g. Zara">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
       <span class="fas fa-search"></span>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <main role="main">

      <section class="jumbotron text-center">
        <div class="container">
          <h1 class="jumbotron-heading">Marketing catchphrase</h1>
          <p class="lead text-muted">Shop from our collection of Women's, Men's wear at affordable prices, greatest quality etc...</p>
          <p class="float-left-custom">
            <a href="#">New</a>
          </p>
          <p class="float-left-custom">
            <a href="#">Women</a>
          </p>
          <p class="float-left-custom">
            <a href="#">Men</a>
          </p>
          <p class="float-left-custom">
            <a href="#">Kids</a>
          </p>
          <p class="float-left-custom">
            <a href="#">Sale</a>
          </p>
          <p class="float-left-custom">
            <a href="#">Our weekly picks</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </section>

      <div class="album py-5 bg-light">
        <div class="container">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="images/thumbnail.svg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="images/thumbnail.svg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="images/thumbnail.svg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="images/thumbnail.svg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="images/thumbnail.svg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="images/thumbnail.svg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="images/thumbnail.svg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="images/thumbnail.svg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="images/thumbnail.svg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: Wow ! I just realized that the URL is relative to the stylesheet and not the webpage HTML. I'm so dumb smh...Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Add the to de bodies css `background-image: url('your-url-here');` and `background-attachment: fixed;` this will make your background fixed!